# Horadric Cache material drops in Patch 2.5

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Bonus Acts have been removed**
>   With this change, completing five bounties in any act will now grant you a Large Horadric Chest containing the same contents as the Horadric and Bonus Caches

[Patch 2.5](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20635663) removes bonus caches from the game but it's unclear how many materials will drop from each cache now. The Diablo Wiki had the following breakdown for the old drop rates per act:

- Normal–Master: one material
- Torment 1–3: two materials
- Torment 4–6: three materials
- Torment 7–9: four materials
- Torment 10: five materials

What is the material breakdown per cache after Patch 2.5? And is there no added benefit for doing bounties on Torment 11–13?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Normal–Master: three materials per cache (Normal-Master),
> - T1–6: six materials per cache
> - T7–9: eight materials per cache
> - T10: ten materials per cache
> - T11: 12 materials per cache
> - T12: 14 materials per cache
> - T13: 16 materials per cache

Verified in [D3 pocket guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o3zTM8P7LDSZRZbg0ipexFr-zZlriuMA-4FC6Lapbkc)